# Grunt - scss is not compiled - gruntFile.js

Tags: sass, gruntjs, watch, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-sass

(Beginner post)

I used Grunt for [this tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d399A.png) :

**Gruntfile.js** :

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    style: 'expanded'
                },
                files: {
                    'css/style.css': 'Component/**/*.scss',
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: 'Component/**/*.scss',
                tasks: ['sass']
            },
        },
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
}
```

It runs without any errors, but it don't take any file. The `style.css` still empty.

When I replace this line :

```js
files: {
    'css/style.css': 'Component/**/*.scss',
}
```

with :

```js
files: {
    'css/style.css': 'Component/header/header.scss',
}
```

Its takes the `.css` file in `header/` correctly.

I don't have any error with either of these two syntaxes.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the grunt files pattern to get all the files recursively in the sources folder:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    style: 'expanded'
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'Component/',
                    src: ['**/*.scss'],
                    dest: 'css/',
                    ext: '.css'
               }]
            }
        },
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: ['Component/**/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['sass']
            },
        },
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
}
```

To use Grunt file patterns you need to specify an object with options instead of the default setting in the form of `'destination': 'source'`. The file pattern object has the following options:

```js
{

    // source directory 
    cwd: String,

    // creates the subdirectories or flatten the content to the destination directory
    flatten: Boolean,

    // remove anything and after the file extension and replace with the ext String
    ext: String,

    // destination folder
    dest: String,

    // source file pattern using minimatch to match files
    src: String|Array

}
```

More about [Grunt file patterns](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file) and [minimatch](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch/blob/master/README.md) file matching patterns.

**Edit** to achieve the desired result (have all the components compiled in to a single file), you will need to do the following:

1. Change the filenames of all of your components, for example change `Component/header/header.scss` to `Component/header/_header.scss`. Files prefixed with `_` will not create any output (Sass default behavior).
2. Then create a bootstrap file (let's call is `style.scss`, containing only the reference to the files you want to merge in to your output css file. For each file add `@import 'header/header';` for `header/_header.scss`. You don't need to add the extension or the `_` prefix.
3. Change the `files` definition of you `sass:dist` task to: `{ 'css/style.css' : ['Component/style.scss'] }`

`Gruntfile.js` will now look like this:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    style: 'expanded'
                },
                files: { 'css/style.css' : ['Component/style.scss'] }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: ['Component/**/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['sass']
            },
        },
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
}
```

That will compile `Component/style.scss` (containing the reference to all your components files) in to `css/style.css`.

Comment: i got this :
`
    Running "watch" task
    Waiting...
    Warning: pattern.indexOf is not a function`

PS: It loops on this error to infinity.

Comment: @BobRock sorry, i was confused about the `watch` taks. I've updated my answer. Now it should work. Let me know.

Comment: it doesn't watch :s, when i change a prop from .scss in "Component/**/*.scss" it do nothing and no error.

Comment: @BobRock All the files are under `Components`? Or do you have nested folders? It's `Component` or `Components`?

Comment: My bad, it work, I forgot to remove the "s". thank you very much for solving my problem.

Comment: @BobRock I'm glad i could help you :-)

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, I saw the compilation be done, so I told myself that his walk but I feel that it is the turn of the "sass" that does not compile.
I delete the "style.css" and the cache folder, and with each change, there is console movement (without error) and finaly "css /" still empty. My "css" folder is at the same level as my "Component" folder.

Comment: @BobRock i'm confused, the folder is called `Component` or `Components`? With or without the `s` at the end?

Comment: It call "Component" without "s"

Comment: @BobRock i forgot one detail. The multiple folders inside `Component`. Check my edit. I added the recursive folder for the compilation `src: ['**/*.scss']`. One detail is that if you want to keep the `header` folder or just merge all to `css`. You will need an extra option in case you don't want to keep all the nested folders.

Comment: Ok I tried and it compiles! But it reproduces the tree of my "Component /", I find footer /, header /, nav / in css /. I would just like a style.css file that contains all compiled .scss.

Comment: @BobRock Well that is not possible. To achieve so you need to make some tweaks. Sass can't create a file with all your files automatically, you need to, create another task to concatenate the result, or (the simpler and better option) create a scss file to act as a bootstrap where you will import all your files. I can discribe both. I recomment the second option.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I will opt for the bootstrap which will call the other sheets with "@import". It's unfortunate that it does not happen, this request fits the model MVC (well I think ^^) no?
In any case, a big final thank you for your help.

Comment: @BobRock check my edit. I added the updated code and explaination.

Comment: @BobRock i've updated a few lines, check the latest edit.

Comment: Thank you, you solution is elegant, there is also this "grunt-contrib-cssmin" but I prefer the natural behavior, so I'll take your hack.